# Caligula Malayalam Short Film: Why did they choose 'caligula' as the title?

Tags: title, short-films

I watched 'Caligula Malayalam Short Movie' on YouTube. It is a satire portraying the blinded religious beliefs. The story is nicely written even though there are some little imperfections with respect to audio and some of the acting style (in terms of clarity).

My question is why did they choose 'Caligula' as the name of this short movie (it has English sub-title), the name is a rare one which someone will think twice before put as a title/name. I don't think there is a connection between the Caligula from History with this.

Youtube Link for this short movie is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Caligula](https://youtu.be/j6TWB2c389c) is Malayalam satire experiment movie based on caste separations in society. [Caligula](https://youtu.be/j6TWB2c389c) was a Roman emperor. He attempted to instate his favorite horse, Incitatus (“Galloper”), as a priest and consul, and ordered a beautiful marble stable built for him, complete with chairs and couches on which Incitatus never sat. Once, at the Circus Maximus, the games ran out of criminals, and the next event was the lions, his favorite. He ordered his Guards to drag the first five rows of spectators into the arena, which they did. These hundreds of people were all devoured for his amusement. We can find many examples to prove that he was not a worthy leader. So we decided [Caligula](https://youtu.be/j6TWB2c389c) is the apt name for the leaders who are not worthy to rule.